# Would this be an appropriate way to append two php variables onto a sql statement without overwriting the data already set in the sql field?

Tags: php, sql

I want to append the $comment variable onto the $notes variable and update the LX table without overwriting the current data inside the note1 field of the LX table. So I've created a variable with the current note data ($notes) and upon update i set $notes + $comments for the particular account... Would this effectively be the correct solution?

```
$patient_ids = $_POST['patient_ids'];
    $comment = strtoupper($_POST['comment']); 
    foreach($patient_ids as $id)
        {
        $patient = new patient($id);
        $patient->insertComment(array('note'=>$comment));


    $ltc_rx_event_id = sql::value ("SELECT id FROM ev.do.ent
                                  WHERE task_id = 'LX' and status = 1 and patient_id = $patient->hex");

    $notes = sql::value("Select note1 FROM ev.do.ent
                        Where task_id = 'LX' and status = 1 and patient_id = $patient->hex");

    sql::query("update ev.do.LX set $notes + $comment where event_id = $ltc_rx_event_id");      
    }

echo "<h3 class='passed'>Comment has been added to " . count($patient_ids) . " patient(s)</h3>";
```

I feel it should work, I'm just wondering if there is something i'm missing or overlooking and if my syntax is correct using the "+" sign to append? Additionally, do i have to concatenate? Thanks for any help, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read this. It will save you some code.

http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/concat.php

Comment: Can you validate this answer please?